# How to move just two columns of pandas dataframe to specific positions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataset of 100 columns like follows:

```
citycode AD700 AD800 AD900 ... AD1980 countryname cityname
```

I want the output dataframe to have columns as follows:

```
citycode countryname cityname AD700 AD800 AD900 ... AD1980
```

I can't use code like

```
cols = [A, B, C, D, E]
df = df[cols]
```

because it would be too cumbersome.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions is:

```
df = df[['citycode', 'countryname', 'cityname'] + list(df.loc[:, 'AD700':'AD1980'])]
```

Note that you compose the list of column names from:

- a "by name" list (first 3),
- a "by range" list (all other columns).

This way, from a source DataFrame like:

```
  citycode  AD700  AD800  AD900  AD1980 countryname cityname
0      CC1     10     20     30      40         CN1      CT1
1      CC2     11     21     31      41         CN2      CT2
```

you will get:

```
  citycode countryname cityname  AD700  AD800  AD900  AD1980
0      CC1         CN1      CT1     10     20     30      40
1      CC2         CN2      CT2     11     21     31      41
```

Comment: I think nice answer.